# why "Product Quick View" JavaScript plugin affects divisions which is not triggered by action?

Tags: javascript, html, css, plugins

I'm pretty new to web designing and I'm using ["Product-Quick-View"](https://codyhouse.co/gem/css-product-quick-view) plugin for my website.
 If you check out the link and click on DEMO button and check the code, you would see something like this:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Product Quick View</h1>
    </header>

    <ul class="cd-items cd-container">
        <li class="cd-item">
            <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Item Preview"/>
            <a href="#0" class="cd-trigger">Quick View</a>
        </li>

        <li class="cd-item">
            <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Item Preview"/>
            <a href="#0" class="cd-trigger">Quick View</a>
        </li>

        <li class="cd-item">
            <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Item Preview">
            <a href="#0" class="cd-trigger">Quick View</a>
        </li>

        <li class="cd-item">
            <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Item Preview"/>
            <a href="#0" class="cd-trigger">Quick View</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="cd-quick-view">
        <div class="cd-slider-wrapper">
            <ul class="cd-slider">
                <li class="selected">
                    <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Product 1"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/item-2.jpg" alt="Product 2"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/item-3.jpg" alt="Product 3"/>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="cd-slider-navigation">
                <li>
                    <a class="cd-next" href="#0">Prev</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="cd-prev" href="#0">Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="cd-item-info">
            <h2>Produt Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia, omnis illo iste ratione. Numquam eveniet quo, ullam itaque expedita impedit. Eveniet, asperiores amet iste repellendus similique reiciendis, maxime laborum praesentium.</p>

            <ul class="cd-item-action">
                <li>
                    <button class="add-to-cart">Add to cart</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#0">Learn more</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="#0" class="cd-close">Close</a>
    </div>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

I changed the code in this way:

```
<div id="Num1">
    <ul class="cd-items cd-container">
        <li class="cd-item">
            <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Item Preview"/>
            <a href="#0" class="cd-trigger">Quick View</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="cd-quick-view">
        <div class="cd-slider-wrapper">
            <ul class="cd-slider">
                <li class="selected">
                    <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Product 1"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/item-2.jpg" alt="Product 2"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/item-3.jpg" alt="Product 3"/>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="cd-slider-navigation">
                <li>
                    <a class="cd-next" href="#0">Prev</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="cd-prev" href="#0">Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="cd-item-info">
            <h2>Produt Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia, omnis illo iste ratione. Numquam eveniet quo, ullam itaque expedita impedit. Eveniet, asperiores amet iste repellendus similique reiciendis, maxime laborum praesentium.</p>

            <ul class="cd-item-action">
                <li>
                    <button class="add-to-cart">Add to cart</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#0">Learn more</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="#0" class="cd-close">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Num2">
    <ul class="cd-items cd-container">
        <li class="cd-item">
            <img src="img/item-4.jpg" alt="Item Preview"/>
            <a href="#0" class="cd-trigger">Quick View</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="cd-quick-view">
        <div class="cd-slider-wrapper">
            <ul class="cd-slider">
                <li class="selected">
                    <img src="img/item-4.jpg" alt="Product 1"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/item-5.jpg" alt="Product 2"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/item-6.jpg" alt="Product 3"/>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="cd-slider-navigation">
                <li>
                    <a class="cd-next" href="#0">Prev</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="cd-prev" href="#0">Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="cd-item-info">
            <h2>Produt Title</h2>
            <p>DIFFERENT DESCRIPTION Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia, omnis illo iste ratione. Numquam eveniet quo, ullam itaque expedita impedit. Eveniet, asperiores amet iste repellendus similique reiciendis, maxime laborum praesentium.</p>

            <ul class="cd-item-action">
                <li>
                    <button class="add-to-cart">Add to cart</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#0">Learn more</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="#0" class="cd-close">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The changes are made because the images in divisions `#Num1, #Num2` are different and I want to get different description for each product.
The problem happens when you click on the `cd-trigger`. The `cd-item-info` of last division pops out on the `cd-item-info` of the first division (even if you have plenty of divisions with item-quick-info style).
I guess the problem lies in `animateQuickView` function in `main.js` in javascript folder.
This code belongs to `main.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//final width --> this is the quick view image slider width
//maxQuickWidth --> this is the max-width of the quick-view panel
var sliderFinalWidth = 400,
        maxQuickWidth = 900;

//open the quick view panel
$('.cd-trigger').on('click', function(event){
    var selectedImage = $(this).parent('.cd-item').children('img'),
        slectedImageUrl = selectedImage.attr('src');

    $('body').addClass('overlay-layer');
    animateQuickView(selectedImage, sliderFinalWidth, maxQuickWidth, 'open');

    //update the visible slider image in the quick view panel
    //you don't need to implement/use the updateQuickView if retrieving the quick view data with ajax
    updateQuickView(slectedImageUrl);
});

//close the quick view panel
$('body').on('click', function(event){
    if( $(event.target).is('.cd-close') || $(event.target).is('body.overlay-layer')) {
        closeQuickView( sliderFinalWidth, maxQuickWidth);
    }
});
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    //check if user has pressed 'Esc'
    if(event.which=='27'){
        closeQuickView( sliderFinalWidth, maxQuickWidth);
    }
});

//quick view slider implementation
$('.cd-quick-view').on('click', '.cd-slider-navigation a', function(){
    updateSlider($(this));
});

//center quick-view on window resize
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if($('.cd-quick-view').hasClass('is-visible')){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(resizeQuickView);
    }
});

function updateSlider(navigation) {
    var sliderConatiner = navigation.parents('.cd-slider-wrapper').find('.cd-slider'),
        activeSlider = sliderConatiner.children('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    if ( navigation.hasClass('cd-next') ) {
        ( !activeSlider.is(':last-child') ) ? activeSlider.next().addClass('selected') : sliderConatiner.children('li').eq(0).addClass('selected'); 
    } else {
        ( !activeSlider.is(':first-child') ) ? activeSlider.prev().addClass('selected') : sliderConatiner.children('li').last().addClass('selected');
    } 
}

function updateQuickView(url) {
    $('.cd-quick-view .cd-slider li').removeClass('selected').find('img[src="'+ url +'"]').parent('li').addClass('selected');
}

function resizeQuickView() {
    var quickViewLeft = ($(window).width() - $('.cd-quick-view').width())/2,
        quickViewTop = ($(window).height() - $('.cd-quick-view').height())/2;
    $('.cd-quick-view').css({
        "top": quickViewTop,
        "left": quickViewLeft,
    });
} 

function closeQuickView(finalWidth, maxQuickWidth) {
    var close = $('.cd-close'),
        activeSliderUrl = close.siblings('.cd-slider-wrapper').find('.selected img').attr('src'),
        selectedImage = $('.empty-box').find('img');
    //update the image in the gallery
    if( !$('.cd-quick-view').hasClass('velocity-animating') && $('.cd-quick-view').hasClass('add-content')) {
        selectedImage.attr('src', activeSliderUrl);
        animateQuickView(selectedImage, finalWidth, maxQuickWidth, 'close');
    } else {
        closeNoAnimation(selectedImage, finalWidth, maxQuickWidth);
    }
}

function animateQuickView(image, finalWidth, maxQuickWidth, animationType) {
    //store some image data (width, top position, ...)
    //store window data to calculate quick view panel position
    var parentListItem = image.parent('.cd-item'),
        topSelected = image.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(),
        leftSelected = image.offset().left,
        widthSelected = image.width(),
        heightSelected = image.height(),
        windowWidth = $(window).width(),
        windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        finalLeft = (windowWidth - finalWidth)/2,
        finalHeight = finalWidth * heightSelected/widthSelected,
        finalTop = (windowHeight - finalHeight)/2,
        quickViewWidth = ( windowWidth * .8 < maxQuickWidth ) ? windowWidth * .8 : maxQuickWidth ,
        quickViewLeft = (windowWidth - quickViewWidth)/2;

    if( animationType == 'open') {
        //hide the image in the gallery
        parentListItem.addClass('empty-box');
        //place the quick view over the image gallery and give it the dimension of the gallery image
        $('.cd-quick-view').css({
            "top": topSelected,
            "left": leftSelected,
            "width": widthSelected,
        }).velocity({
            //animate the quick view: animate its width and center it in the viewport
            //during this animation, only the slider image is visible
            'top': finalTop+ 'px',
            'left': finalLeft+'px',
            'width': finalWidth+'px',
        }, 1000, [ 400, 20 ], function(){
            //animate the quick view: animate its width to the final value
            $('.cd-quick-view').addClass('animate-width').velocity({
                'left': quickViewLeft+'px',
                'width': quickViewWidth+'px',
            }, 300, 'ease' ,function(){
                //show quick view content
                $('.cd-quick-view').addClass('add-content');
            });
        }).addClass('is-visible');
    } else {
        //close the quick view reverting the animation
        $('.cd-quick-view').removeClass('add-content').velocity({
            'top': finalTop+ 'px',
            'left': finalLeft+'px',
            'width': finalWidth+'px',
        }, 300, 'ease', function(){
            $('body').removeClass('overlay-layer');
            $('.cd-quick-view').removeClass('animate-width').velocity({
                "top": topSelected,
                "left": leftSelected,
                "width": widthSelected,
            }, 500, 'ease', function(){
                $('.cd-quick-view').removeClass('is-visible');
                parentListItem.removeClass('empty-box');
            });
        });
    }
}
function closeNoAnimation(image, finalWidth, maxQuickWidth) {
    var parentListItem = image.parent('.cd-item'),
        topSelected = image.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(),
        leftSelected = image.offset().left,
        widthSelected = image.width();

    $('body').removeClass('overlay-layer');
    parentListItem.removeClass('empty-box');
    $('.cd-quick-view').velocity("stop").removeClass('add-content animate-width is-visible').css({
        "top": topSelected,
        "left": leftSelected,
        "width": widthSelected,
    });
}
});
```

The whole project (including Javascript, CSS files and etc) can be found in [this link](https://github.com/CodyHouse/product-quick-view)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a unique div with cd-quick-view class for every item and mark them with different ids.

```
<div id="first-item" class="cd-quick-view">
        <div class="cd-slider-wrapper">
            <ul class="cd-slider">
                <li class="selected"><img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Product 1"></li>
                <li><img src="img/item-2.jpg" alt="Product 2"></li>
                <li><img src="img/item-3.jpg" alt="Product 3"></li>
            </ul> <!-- cd-slider -->

            <ul class="cd-slider-navigation">
                <li><a class="cd-next" href="#0">Prev</a></li>
                <li><a class="cd-prev" href="#0">Next</a></li>
            </ul> <!-- cd-slider-navigation -->
        </div> <!-- cd-slider-wrapper -->

        <div class="cd-item-info">
            <h2>First Item</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia, omnis illo iste ratione. Numquam eveniet quo, ullam itaque expedita impedit. Eveniet, asperiores amet iste repellendus similique reiciendis, maxime laborum praesentium.</p>

            <ul class="cd-item-action">
                <li><button class="add-to-cart">Add to cart</button></li>                   
                <li><a href="#0">Learn more</a></li>    
            </ul> <!-- cd-item-action -->
        </div> <!-- cd-item-info -->
        <a href="#0" class="cd-close">Close</a>
    </div> <!-- cd-quick-view -->
    <div id="second-item" class="cd-quick-view">
        <div class="cd-slider-wrapper">
            <ul class="cd-slider">
                <li class="selected"><img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Product 1"></li>
                <li><img src="img/item-2.jpg" alt="Product 2"></li>
                <li><img src="img/item-3.jpg" alt="Product 3"></li>
            </ul> <!-- cd-slider -->

            <ul class="cd-slider-navigation">
                <li><a class="cd-next" href="#0">Prev</a></li>
                <li><a class="cd-prev" href="#0">Next</a></li>
            </ul> <!-- cd-slider-navigation -->
        </div> <!-- cd-slider-wrapper -->

        <div class="cd-item-info">
            <h2>Second Item</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia, omnis illo iste ratione. Numquam eveniet quo, ullam itaque expedita impedit. Eveniet, asperiores amet iste repellendus similique reiciendis, maxime laborum praesentium.</p>

            <ul class="cd-item-action">
                <li><button class="add-to-cart">Add to cart</button></li>                   
                <li><a href="#0">Learn more</a></li>    
            </ul> <!-- cd-item-action -->
        </div> <!-- cd-item-info -->
        <a href="#0" class="cd-close">Close</a>
    </div> <!-- cd-quick-view -->
```

Add those ids as hrefs to cd-trigger a tags: href="#first-item"

```
        <li class="cd-item">
            <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Item Preview">
            <a href="#first-item" class="cd-trigger">Quick View</a>
        </li> <!-- cd-item -->

        <li class="cd-item">
            <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Item Preview">
            <a href="#second-item" class="cd-trigger">Quick View</a>
        </li> <!-- cd-item -->
```

First get href of the a tags when clicked then with just a quick change in animateQuickView add href property and pass it through the function.

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');

animateQuickView(selectedImage, sliderFinalWidth, maxQuickWidth, 'open', href);
```

After that you should replace '.cd-quick-view' with href for open animation part:

```
$(href).css({
    "top": topSelected,
    "left": leftSelected,
    "width": widthSelected,
}).velocity({
    //animate the quick view: animate its width and center it in the viewport
    //during this animation, only the slider image is visible
    'top': finalTop+ 'px',
    'left': finalLeft+'px',
    'width': finalWidth+'px',
}, 1000, [ 400, 20 ], function(){
    //animate the quick view: animate its width to the final value
    $(href).addClass('animate-width').velocity({
        'left': quickViewLeft+'px',
        'width': quickViewWidth+'px',
    }, 300, 'ease' ,function(){
        //show quick view content
        $(href).addClass('add-content');
    });
}).addClass('is-visible');
```

The complete changed files:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OC9uj8haP0t-EBGuJe1dwR4_5zjLq7T_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: After passing this `href` through function, how am I supposed to use it? I changed the code as you suggested, but unfortunately it didn't work. can u add the necessary changes inside the function to get the code work?

Comment: By the way, Thank you for the time you spent to suggest me your idea. (Koochiketim dash saeed). I would be happy if you find me in telegram (@masouduut94)

Comment: I have updated the answer and use complete file as refrence : 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OC9uj8haP0t-EBGuJe1dwR4_5zjLq7T_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Cool job Saeed. This is exactly what I was looking for. I got the answer, but in case that it would be of use for someone else, please update the answer and rewrite the `main.js` in your answer (and if possible explain it thoroughly). Thank you again.

Comment: GREAT GREAT ANSWER !!! It saved me .... It´s the only way to open different quick-views popups within the same page. I do not understand how this is not explained on github ! THANKS